# jquery datatable add column at runtime

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a html table with 2 columns. I am getting the data in an ajax call and adding 2 more columns to the table dynamically so that it become column when jquery datatable plugin applies on this.

```
aoColumns.push({ "mDataProp": someVariable });
```

later in the same function the datatable is applied on the table and the following code is provided for the datatable plugin

```
"aoColumns": aoColumns,
```

Now after the data load is done I can see 4 columns(headers including 2 dynamic) and the data but the data is only bound to 2 headers means under each header column 2 data column in present and under the dynamic columns no data column is present.

Need help how I can achieve this or if there is any way so that datatable columns are automatically populated from json object keys.

Thank you

Comment: are you using http://datatables.net/

Comment: Nope the title says.. Its Jquery datatable !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works same way. I figured it out the data columns was not mapped properly with the header column in json.